# How to skip and take within Babaganoush using javascript

Tags: babaganoush-sitefinity

How would you skip and take records from using the webservices of Babaganoush?
I tried this:

```
$.get('http://localhost/egz/api/mediafiles?take=10&skip=100').done(function(response) {
   console.log(response);
});
```

That didn't work. Only the 'take' parameters seems to work?

I thought that when I can use this in C# code:

```
BabaManagers.News.GetAll(
   filter: x => x.Visible,
   take: 25,
   skip: 75
);
```

... it would also work client side.
I have to say that I created my own Api Controller for a DynamicType, but I think that shouldn't matter?

Also, any reason why **take** and **skip** are reversed, since in most cases it is **skip** and then **take**.

Comment: This is not complete but hoping to get this released soon. The reason we put "take" first is because many times "take" is supplied without "skip". There are many scenarios where I would simply like to limit the number of results only, the signature would be easier to leave of the "skip from the request. This shouldn't be a problem for Kendo or 3rd party ajax consumers correct? Since it is supplying the parameter names in the request.

Answer (score 0):

This has been complete with the latest version of Babaganoush:

```
http://localhost/api/news?take=5&skip=10
```